# gcc inline assembler implicit function declaration on Powerpc arch

Tags: c, gcc, freebsd, inline-assembly, powerpc

I'm trying to compile code which is calling multiple times the following makro:

```
#define MULADD(i, j) \
    asm( \
    " mullw  16,%6,%7       \n\t" \
    " addc   %0,%0,16       \n\t" \
    " mulhwu 16,%6,%7       \n\t" \
    " adde   %1,%1,16       \n\t" \
    " addze  %2,%2          \n\t" \
    :"=r"(c0), "=r"(c1), "=r"(c2):"0"(c0), "1"(c1), "2"(c2), "r"(i), "r"(j):"16");
```

where ever MULAD is called i get the

> error: expected ')' before ':' token

error notification.

And the Error code looks like this:

```
../../src/math/mul.c: In function 'mul_comba':
../../src/math/mul.c:787: warning: implicit declaration of function 'asm'
../../src/math/mul.c:787: error: expected ')' before ':' token
../../src/math/mul.c: In function 'mul_comba_small':
../../src/math/mul.c:816: error: expected ')' before ':' token
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and what does the implicit declaration mean?
As far as i know `asm()` is compiler reserved and so not an function that has to be declared, has it? and if so, what I had to include? I'm realy out of knowledge.

EDIT:
I'm using gcc 4.2.1 the arch is as tagged powerpc (32Bit) and the OS is freeBSD 9.2

Comment: You're not using any of `gcc`'s flags that disallow extensions (e.g. `-ansi` or `-std=c99`) when you compile `mul.c`, are you?

Comment: I'm using -std=c99 does this dissallow extensions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the C standard (appendix J.5.10), `asm` is a common language extension.  In `gcc` it is disallowed (together with all `gcc` extensions), if you use a flag like `-std=c90`, `-std=c99` or `-ansi`.  If you want C99 with `gcc` extensions, use `-std=gnu99` instead.